# Not getting output of a process (SFC.exe /VERIFYONLY). The Process.StandardOutPut.ReadToEnd is giving output with /n/0/n included in various spaces

Tags: c#, .net, windows, command-line, process

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "sfc.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /VERIFYONLY";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.Start();
            string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

/*processOutput is getting an output like "\n\0\n\0\n\0M\0i\0c\0r\0o\0s\0o\0f\0t\0 \0(\0R\0)\0 \0W\"*/
                string processOutput= output + error;
                p.WaitForExit();

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, sfc writes redirected output as Unicode using WriteFile. Then you can help a consumer to decode it by specifying

```cs
p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

On a related note - watch out for pipes buffer overflow. You're reading the redirected output with blocking calls to `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`. You can get a deadlock when you're blocked reading out one stream while the child process is trying to make a write to another. The easiest fix would be using `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync` for at least one stream:

```cs
var output_task = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string output = output_task.Result;
```